# Core data relationship returning no value

Tags: ios, database, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have 2 entities with Driver and Work_Shift.
Driver has one to many relation with Work_Shift and Work_SHift has one to one relation with Driver.

I am trying to fetch Driver detail while fetching Work_shift data, but i am getting empty values.

Here is my code:

This is the code to fetch Work_Shift detail along with relationship within it.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Work_Shift"];

    //[fetch setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"work_shifts.id"]];

    fetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;

    work_shift_results = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    if([work_shift_results count]>0)
    {
        Work_Shift *shift = [work_shift_results objectAtIndex:0];
        NSSet *driverSet = shift.work_shifts;
        NSArray *driverArray = [driverSet allObjects];

        NSLog(@"Shift: %@",shift);
    }
```

This is the output i am getting

```
<Work_Shift: 0x15678540> (entity: Work_Shift; id: 0x15665460 <x-coredata://7059F32C-63F0-4B2C-A104-5FA339AE2473/Work_Shift/p2> ; data: {
    block = nil;
    "dest_mine_loc_id" = 0;
    "driver_id" = 6;
    "end_date" = nil;
    weight = 0;
    "work_shifts" =     (
    );
})
```

I have checked and there is are entries in Driver table. I also tried uncommenting the code above, still i get the same result.

The entities are

```
@class Work_Shift;

@interface Driver : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * contact_number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * is_active;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Work_Shift *driver;

@end
```

and

```
@class Driver;

@interface Work_Shift : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * block;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * dest_mine_loc_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * driver_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * end_date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * excavator_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * material_type_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * mine_location_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * relative_level_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * shift_type_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * start_date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * truck_type_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * weight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *work_shifts;
@end

@interface Work_Shift (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addWork_shiftsObject:(Driver *)value;
- (void)removeWork_shiftsObject:(Driver *)value;
- (void)addWork_shifts:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeWork_shifts:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Where is the code that associates Work_shift with Driver?

Comment: i have created entities using NSManagedObject class, i am not sure of what associates here means.. :|

Comment: Post details of you entity relationships. Seems you are using a foreign key to associate the driver with the workshift. Usually it's better to directly associate the objects.  Workshift.driver = driver.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald : Edited my question with entities

Comment: Ok so each workshift belongs to one driver. Instead of using driverID just create a property DRIVER *driver on Workshift. Then create a workshift object and a driver object and set workshift.driver=driver.

Comment: On the Drivers object have a relationship workShifts which is a To-Many relationship to workShifts. Driver can have many workShifts. Set this as the inverse of the driver relationship on workShifts.

Comment: Once you set workshift.driver = driver then you can access all the drivers workShifts using driver.workShifts

Comment: Get your head around relationships and get rid of all the foreign keys (IDs). Core Data is an object model not a relational database.

Comment: Sorry, I can write up a decent answer for you tomorrow if you're still stuck.

Comment: @kapsym so you still stuck then ?

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Thanks to you, i figured it out and its working just fine now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better example as promised

The model showing the relationships

[image]

The entity attributes and relationships
[image]

[image]

Sample code to create entity and set attributes and relationships. If you want I can email you the sample app.

```
- (void)addEntities {

    Driver *driver1 = (Driver *)[self createNewDriverMethod1:@"Driver 1" address:@"Address 1"];
    Driver *driver2 = [self createNewDriverMethod2:@"Driver 2" address:@"Address 2"];

    Excavator *excavator1 = [self createNewExcavator:@"EXC001" make:@"CAT" model:@"DX1000"];
    Excavator *excavator2 = [self createNewExcavator:@"EXC002" make:@"CAT" model:@"DX2000"];

    // Current date as shift start date & time
    NSDate *shiftStartDate = [NSDate date];

    Workshift *workshift1 = [self createNewWorkshift:shiftStartDate hours:8.0 driver:driver1];
    workshift1.excavator = excavator1;


    Workshift *workshift2 = [self createNewWorkshift:shiftStartDate hours:8.0 driver:driver2];
    workshift2.excavator = excavator2;

    NSError *error;

    if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@" error saving data %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }

    [self listWorkShifts];


}
- (void)listWorkShifts {

    NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [req setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Driver" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]]];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *result = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];

    if (result == nil) {
        NSLog(@" error fetching Driver list %@", error);
        return;
    }

    for (Driver *driver in result) {
        NSLog(@" Driver: %@", driver.name);


        for (Workshift *shift in driver.workshifts) {

            NSLog(@"   SHIFT");
            NSLog(@"         Start: %@", [shift.startDate description]); // Get date back as string
            NSLog(@"           End: %@", [shift.endDate description]); // Get date back as string
            NSLog(@"     Excavator: %@, %@", shift.excavator.make, shift.excavator.model);
            NSLog(@"   ");

        }
        NSLog(@"   ");
    }
}
- (NSManagedObject *)createNewDriverMethod1:(NSString *)name address:(NSString *)address
{
    NSManagedObject *newDriver = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Driver"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    [newDriver setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
    [newDriver setValue:address forKey:@"address"];

    return newDriver;
}

- (Driver *)createNewDriverMethod2:(NSString *)name address:(NSString *)address
{
    Driver *newDriver = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Driver"
                               inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    newDriver.name = name;
    newDriver.address = address;
    return newDriver;
}
- (Workshift *)createNewWorkshift:(NSDate *)startDate hours:(float)hours driver:(Driver *)driver
{
    Workshift *newWorkshift = [NSEntityDescription
                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Workshift"
                         inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    [newWorkshift setValue:startDate forKey:@"startDate"];

    // time interval in seconds
    NSTimeInterval interval = hours * 60 * 60;

    NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];

    [newWorkshift setValue:endDate forKey:@"endDate"];
    [newWorkshift setValue:driver forKey:@"driver"];

    return newWorkshift;
}
- (Excavator *)createNewExcavator:(NSString *)identifier make:(NSString *)make model:(NSString *)model
{
    Excavator *newExcavator = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Excavator"
                               inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    [newExcavator setValue:identifier forKey:@"identifier"];
    [newExcavator setValue:make forKey:@"make"];
    [newExcavator setValue:model forKey:@"model"];

    return newExcavator;
}
```